# Why LocalStorage Stays Undeleted?

Tags: html, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I know this was asked before but this is what I'm experiencing - 
I'm working on a Chrome extension that needs to persist some data and I'm using localStorage for that . When I go to **Settings->Tools->Clear Browsing Data** and check everything (including 'since the beginning of time') , I would expect the localStorage of my background page to clear . 
However everything stays put. **The localstorage wasn't deleted**!
It's not that I don't like that behavior , it's actually pretty great for my app , but is this normal ? Shouldn't localStorage delete once the user tries to clear everything , just like cookies should delete?

P.S 
I found this nice blog that asks and tries to answer the same question : 
http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2011/03/21/clearing-cache-has-no-effect-on-html5-localstorage-or-sessionstorage/
Seems like the behavior changes from browser to browser . The behavior I talked about happens on Chrome 28.0.1500.71 m

Answer (score 2):

This bug is not normal behavior. ( to answer your question )

I'm calling this a bug because someone might be using a computer at a library with some type of locally hosted application.   **There is a clear expectation that  data is not retained in any way under a purge called "beginning of time"**

Firefox purges localStorage data when you clear all browser data.  It does this if the file is stored locally or hosted on a web domain.

Chrome purges localStorage data only if you code is hosted on a domain.

**I made a video of this bug..**
https://youtu.be/CgojKg4v7X0

Save this URL with HTML/JS a local drive to reproduce the bug...
https://html5dataprivacy.github.io/

steps:
- load a local web page containing  javascript HTML5 storage code

- interact with the page that stores your data in a way that changes the data
- clear everything in history until the beginning of time
- give the keyboard and mouse to another user in the library or public cafe...

result:  That javascript storage is retained , another person can see your data...

expected result:  The data is purged for the new person at the keyboard

notes:  This bug does not exist on Firefox current version as of April 19th, 2017. Does not fail if chrome is working off a hosted domain

Workaround:  After you clear things to the beginning of time you must open up the console and type "localStorage.clear()"

ps: please be kind. This is my first attempt to answer on StackOverFlow :)